# How to use NSPredicate with chained virtual property?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

Assume two ManagedObject backed by Sqlite:

1.) A `User` which has two properties, `firstname` and `lastname` and a virtual (transient) property `fullname` which is read-only.

```
@interface User : NSManagedObject
...
@property NSString *firstname;
@property NSString *lastname;
@property (readonly) NSString *fullname;
@end

@implementation User
...
- (NSString*)fullname
{
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.firstname, self.lastname];
}
@end
```

2.) A `Message` which has besides several other properties a relationship to exactly one User stored in `sender` property.

```
@interface Message : NSManagedObject
@property User *sender;
@end
```

I want to fetch all instances of Message with a certain sender's fullname. This is the NSPredicate I am constructing:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sender.fullname CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"Searched Name"]]
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an `NSInvalidArgumentException` once I start searching:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (sender.fullname CONTAINS[cd] "S")'
```

Comment: You may want to check out the chapter on searching text in our book: https://www.objc.io/books/core-data/ — it talks about how to make string search work reliably and fast. Unicode is tricky. Here's an article that touches upon some of this: https://www.objc.io/issues/9-strings/unicode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use transient properties in a fetch request predicate, this is because the data you're trying to use doesn't exist in the SQLite database.

You need to rewrite the predicate to use only `firstname` and `last name`.

You may want to do that with `BEGINSWITH` and `ENDSWITH` and then you may also want to run a second filter once you have the results of the fetch to ensure you don't have any false positives in the result set.

Alternatively you can make the full name non-transient and then it can be used in the predicate. In this case you would implement custom accessor methods to ensure that any update also applies to the full name.

Comment: As a sort of +1, I took the alternative approach in my project, including the custom setters to update dependent properties.  At the end of the day, being able to do proper fetches, especially with NSFetchedResultsControllers, was too important.